# How to choose an element from divs having the same classnames (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium which is probably why I am stuck.

Here is the screenshot showing inspect where two divs are almost identical but they both have another div inside containing different text values: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aivEh.png).

Could I somehow choose the div I want by checking if `getText()` is equal to ...?
I found the following way but as far as I know, I would never know the order of the stream:

```
 new ArrayList<>(chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sign-up-row']"))).get(1).click();
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xpath like below:

example for `//div[@class='sign-up-row']` this node

**use  `text()`:**

```
//div[@class='sign-up-row' and .//span[text()='Remember me.')]]
```

**Or use with `contains`:**

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Remember')]/ancestor::div[@class='sign-up-row']
```

**Use the dot `.` can find inner element:**

```
//div[@class='sign-up-row' and contains(., 'Remember')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xpath using the text present in the tag within the div tag. This would return the specific element you are interested in.
Example for the xpath:

```
//div/div[text()='textforcomparison']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below approach.

```
    List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sign-up-row']"));
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        if(lst.get(i).getText().equals("Text to Be Compared")) {
            lst.get(i).click();
            //If you want to break the foe loop after the match 
            break;
        }
    }
```